Why are all of the documentclass of my tex file on overleaf changed to \documentclass[reprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}?
I suppose I use \documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn]{revtex4-2} originally, and today I opened the overleaf and found that all these changed to \documentclass[reprint,nofootinbib]{revtex4-2}, accompanied by warnings:
Class revtex4-2 Warning: No type size specified, using default 10.
‪/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revtex4-2.cls‬
Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <4.56004> not available
‪./ACSQST.tex‬
Font shape `OML/cmm/b/it' in size <4.56004> not available
‪./ACSQST.tex‬
Font shape `OMS/cmsy/b/n' in size <4.56004> not available

Sounds like a good question for the Overleaf support to me …
